# Automatically close a vtk window befor another vtk window is open

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, vtk

I have Visual studio MFC project which is integrated with VTK. A Button click on my project will generates a VTK window and I want to close that VTK window when I clicked the same button for the second time and open a new VTK window.

My current project will generate VTK windows for each button click without closing the previously opened windows.

My button contain the following code lines to call the .cpp file where I have written down the code for the VTK window.

```
RectangleShape C1;
C1.RectangleGraphic(redVal,greenVal,blueVal,length,Height,Width);
```

Comment: What kind of object is "RectangleShape" ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VTK but when you create the window you can store a pointer to it in your class

```
CWnd *pVTKWindow = CodeThatOpensTheWindow();
```

then you can use `CWnd::CloseWindow` or `CWnd::DestroyWindow`, to close or destroy it.
Also you can use `CWnd::ShowWindow` to show or hide the window instead of destroying or closing it, if you don't actually need to destroy or close it.
but surely you have to provide more info about your application so we are able to provide you better solutions.